# Insert Select will not convert or cast NVARCHAR to Float

Tags: select, insert, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I'm am trying to do an insert select statement to move all data from one table to another..  Two of the columns in the source table have a datatype of `NVARCHAR` and the destination tables have a datatype of `Float`.

I have attempted to use `cast` and `convert` but I keep getting the following message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table
      ([SCAC]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Orgin]
      ,[Destination Low Zip]
      ,[Destination High Zip]
      ,[Class]
      ,[Minimum Charge]
      )

SELECT [SCAC]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Origin]
      ,cast([Destination Low Zip]   as float)
      ,cast([Destination High Zip]  as float)
      ,[Class]
      ,[Minimum Charge]

  FROM source_table
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE TRY_CONVERT(float,[Destination Low Zip]) IS NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(float,[Destination High Zip]) IS NULL` return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the data I'd be guessing that the column(s) may have some NULL data, which will throw this error so the code should be

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table
  ([SCAC]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Orgin]
  ,[Destination Low Zip]
  ,[Destination High Zip]
  ,[Class]
  ,[Minimum Charge]
  )
SELECT [SCAC]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Origin]
  ,cast(ISNULL([Destination Low Zip],0)   as float)
  ,cast(ISNULL([Destination High Zip],0)  as float)
  ,[Class]
  ,[Minimum Charge]
FROM source_table
```

And if you want the NULLs then

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table
  ([SCAC]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Orgin]
  ,[Destination Low Zip]
  ,[Destination High Zip]
  ,[Class]
  ,[Minimum Charge]
  )
SELECT [SCAC]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Origin]
  ,NULLIF(CAST(ISNULL([Destination Low Zip],0)   as float), 0)
  ,NULLIF(CAST(ISNULL([Destination High Zip],0)  as float),0)
  ,[Class]
  ,[Minimum Charge]
 FROM source_table
```